# how to calculate model accuracy in rstudio for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

How do you calculate the model accuracy in RStudio for logistic regression. The dataset is from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/santoshd3/bank-customers).

```
set.seed(1000)
split = sample.split(query$Exited, SplitRatio = 0.65)
train = subset(query, split==TRUE)
test = subset(query, split==FALSE)
model = glm(Exited ~ CreditScore + Gender + Age + Balance + IsActiveMember, data = train, family=binomial)
summary(model)
predict = predict(model, type="response", newdata=test)
table(test$Exited, predict > 0.5)
```

FALSE TRUE

0  2717   70

1   606  107

Is it possible to extract the values from the table to calculate the accuracy using variables or is there a function to get the accuracy?

```
# Accuracy of model:
(2717+107)/(2717+70+606+107)
```

Is it more accurate? I'm getting different values.

```
(2717+107)/(2717+70+606+107)
```

accuracy is 0.8068571

```
Accuracy(y_pred = pred, y_true = train$Exited)
```

accuracy is 0.8087692 using ML metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the package ML metrics

```
MLmetrics::Accuracy(predicted, actual)
```

There is also a lot of different error methods you can calculate within that package